# Unable to Calculate Average from JSON Array

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a for loop that is parsing a JSON array and returning a list of string values with one decimal place. I have converted these strings to int values and casted as floats:

```
result = requests.get(url)
raw = result.json()

print (Fore.YELLOW + "\nMost Recent Sold Listings: \n" + Fore.GREEN)
for item in (raw["findCompletedItemsResponse"][0]["searchResult"][0 ["item"]): 
    price = item["sellingStatus"][0]["convertedCurrentPrice"][0]['__value__']
    int_price = int(float(price))

print (int_price)
```

These are the converted int values it is returning:

`538` `610` `626` `650` `726` `800` `829` `835` `843` `870` `950` `960` `980`

I am attempting to call the sum() function to add all these int values together and then divide by len:

```
sum(int_price) / len(int_price)
```

However, I am getting an error "**Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not iterable**"

The goal is to create an average of the values returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory: The sum() and len() commands expect an input that is iterable, like an array. int_price, however, is just an individual integer value - it doesn't have a length and you can't iterate over it to produce a sum.

Comment: You are missing a `]` at the end of your for loop specifically `[0 ["item"]` has a missing bracket

Comment: Hint: what you are trying to do is similar to `sum(5)` which is not possible but `sum[5]` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs sum() and len() are builtin which expects iterables. An iterable is essentially on which you can iterate over like list, string etc.

> An iterable is an object that has an **iter** method which returns an
>   iterator, or which defines a **getitem** method that can take
>   sequential indexes starting from zero (and raises an IndexError when
>   the indexes are no longer valid). So an iterable is an object that you
>   can get an iterator from.

**sum()**

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns
>   the total. start defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally
>   numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

**len()**

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may
>   be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a
>   collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

Integer on the other hand is not an iterable and it consists of single value. In order to solve the issue you can create a new list
for easy calulcation and while iterating the json values append the int/float values to this list.

```
new_list=[]
```

in `for` loop

```
int_price = int(price)
new_list.append(int_price)
```

Now you should be able to calculate average

```
sum(new_list) / float(len(new_list)) # float conversion to get the final result as floats
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to explain this. I created a list as you suggested and I am able to calculate an average now. The only change I had to make was to convert the int to float inside the loop (otherwise I was getting an "invalid literal for int() with base 10" exception).